# How can I safely perform operations on files or directories with dashes or hyphens?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was trying to rename a file named `12F-XYZ.pdf` to `13F-XYX_ABX.pdf`.

Both the original and the required names have hyphens. I know that for spaces we use `\` to overcome problems, but what can we do in the case of hyphens or any other character that might be treated specially by the shell or by commands?

Comment: Hyphen characters (especially in the middle of a file name) have no special meaning in any shell I know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As David Foerster pointed out in a comment, hyphens (-) are not treated specially by the shell. So as far as your example is concerned you can simply do:

```
mv 12F-XYZ.pdf 13F-XYX_ABX.pdf
```

But if you have a space or literal escape character (backslash) or any other that needs to be escaped, you can escape those with either the escape character i.e. `\` or put the whole name inside quotes `'` `'` so that the content inside the quotes is treated literally.

Here is an example:

```
mv 12F-XYZ.pdf 50M -XYZ.pdf  ##Wrong
mv 12F-XYZ.pdf 50M\ -XYZ.pdf  ##Right
mv 12F-XYZ.pdf '50M -XYZ.pdf'  ##Right
```

A rule of thumb would be to escape it while in doubt.
[This article on special characters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) would be a very good read for you.

As muru pointed out in comments, you could have problem in case of a leading hyphen as many commands treat arguments beginning with a hyphen as options. In that case you can use either of the following:

```
mv -- foo.bar -foo.bar
mv foo.bar ./-foo.bar
```

The `--` indicates the end of switches for the previous command (in this case `mv`). Not all commands support `--` so using the second option (`./-foo.bar`) would be more reliable.

Comment: Leading hyphens may cause problems. In which case: `./-foo.bar`.