# I have a directory named -H and would like to change the name of it

Tags: filesystem, directory

I am taking a class at Pluralsight and made the mistake of typing 'express -H' as instructed. Now I have a dir named -H and Ubuntu will not let me access it or otherwise deal with it. I would like to rename it - any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename it (to `foobar.dir`):

```
mv ./-H foobar.dir
```

to access it:

```
cd ./-H
```

I would suggest you to look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/591939/216503) to get more idea on this.

Comment: Whoa - thank you. I googled the heck out it and could not find the answer!

Comment: @Nuhuxi: happy to help..read the link i provided in the answer to get better idea on this..also don't forget to select the answer as the right answer to your question by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: heemayl - I would have selected this as the right answer yesterday but there is some kind of minimum time limit. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nuhuxi: Happy to help :)